# Definitive restore method for cusp iOS

Tags: ios, itunes, restore

I want to upgrade to iOS 13 but just in case my CarPlay doesn't like it, I need to be able to revert.

This will be before Apple stops signing iOS 12.4.1 which I imagine I'll have a few days to deal with.

I have a saved 12.4.1 ipsw & the new 13.0 ipsw.
My data is synced & backed, with encryption, to iTunes as of right now.

If I upgrade then change my mind immediately [within minutes/hours at most], how difficult is it to persuade the phone to restore to 12.4.1?

Is it simply a case of turning off Find my iPhone, then choosing which ipsw to restore from, or am I going to be in for a fight?